# How to model a blog based on DDD practices?

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design, modeling, ddd-repositories

Suppose we want to model a blog based on Domain Driven Design practices. The main entities are Blog, User, Post, Comment and Like. So, how do you define your aggregates, value-objects, and repositories? By DDD definition, Since all of the entities are dependent on the Blog entity, it seems that there is just one large aggregate with Blog as it's aggregate root. However, It brings too many consistency and performance challenges.

Answer (score 2):

You should model your aggregates based on consistency requirements. The larger is the consistency boundary => the larger is the aggregate.

> Do you think is it valid to have just one aggregate root with Blog as it's root. From there we can have blog.Posts, blog.Posts(id).Comments, and blog.Posts(id).Likes

Having only a big/god-like aggregate `Blog` offers the biggest consistency boundary but it drastically affects the performance. Think about this: every time somebody creates/publishes/unpublishes/likes a post, posts/edits/deletes a comment then the entire `Blog` aggregate is loaded, the action is performed on it's nested entities and then it is persisted. All in a single transaction.

I recommend you to read [this blog post](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=838) about designing aggregates.